# How should I attribute the glyphicons component of Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

On GitHub's Twitter bootstrap pages the [Base CSS page's section on icons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) says this:

> Glyphicons Halflings are normally not available for free, but an arrangement between Bootstrap and the Glyphicons creators have made this possible at no cost to you as developers. As a thank you, we ask you to include an optional link back to Glyphicons whenever practical.

Is there a standard form this attribution should take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution is presumably to attribute [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com) in the same way that Twitter do in the footer of the bootstrap GitHub pages, namely:

```
<p>Icons from <a href="http://glyphicons.com">Glyphicons Free</a>, licensed 
under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/">CC BY 3.0</a>.</p>
```

This does seem to gloss over the fact that the halflings are specifically *not* covered by the Creative Commons licence, but I guess if it's good enough for Twitter then it should be okay for the rest of us.

Answer (score 3):

> GLYPHICONS Halflings font is also released as an extension of a Bootstrap www.getbootstrap.com for free and it is released under the same license as Bootstrap. **While you are not required to include attribution on your Bootstrap-based projects, I would certainly appreciate any form of support, even a nice Tweet is enough.** Of course if you want, you can say thank you and support me by buying more icons on GLYPHICONS.com.

This's from https://glyphicons.com/license/. I hope this help you.

For me, I will make credit page and put link back to glyphicons. I don't want to put link at footer because this's under Apache 2.0 license not CC. I really appreciate their work but putting link at footer is about SEO too.